# Unable to define bean in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have defined a class annotated it with @Configuration and defined method init and Defined it with annotation @Bean but when i m trying to access that bean using auto-wired it gives me an error
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

```
┌─────┐
|  Sum defined in class path resource [com/example/Application/Appconfig.class]

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Appconfig {

    @Bean
    public int Sum(int a,int b){

        int c=a+b;
        return c;
    }
```

**And my controller class**

```
 @Autowired
    Appconfig appconfig;


    @PostMapping(value = "/api/{id1}/{id2}")
    public void math(@PathVariable int id1,@PathVariable int id2){

        appconfig.Sum(id1,id2);
        System.out.println(id1);
        System.out.println(id2);
        System.out.println(appconfig.Sum(id1,id2));


    }
```

**Error**

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  Sum defined in class path resource [com/example/Application/Appconfig.class]
└─────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Your dependencies are circular, which means, that to create `A` you need `B` which needs `A`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Appconfig {

    public int Sum(int a,int b){

        int c=a+b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

will work but isn't a good practice. Configuration classes shouldn't be `@Autowired`.

In Spring Boot you can create `@Bean`s in two ways. One is defining a class as a `@Bean`:

```
@Bean
public class MyBean {

}
```

The other way is via the method:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Both of the above, will create `@Bean`s when creating the `Context`.

Comment: There's nothing "proper" about dropping both `@Configuration` and `@Bean` on a class, and it's considered bad practice in Spring Boot to define beans in the application bootstrap class. (In very compact examples, add a nested class.)

Comment: @chrylis I agree. I'll add it to the answer

Comment: A `@Configuration` is a special bean which is annotated with `@Component` (meta annotation). `AppConfig` is a bean and can be injected